# Issue with loop function

Tags: r, function, loops

```
df_list <- list(tt_202,tt_200,tt_220,tt_210,tt_212,tt_240,tt_242,tt_230,tt_LEF,tt_FR,tt_CE)

multipetal <- function(df, n) {
    (df[[n,"q3"]]+df[[n,"max"]]+df[[n+1,"q1"]]+df[[n+1,"min"]])/4}

df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) transform(x,borne=NA))

for (i in 1:length(df_list)){
  for(j in 1:(nrow(df_list[[i]]))-1) {
assign(df_list[[i]][j,"borne"], multipetal(df=df_list[[i]],n=j))}}
```

Hello,
I have 11 dataframes with different number of rows in a list and I'd like to assign the value of a function for each n row (except the last one) in a new column. The function is the mean of Q3 and Max of the row n (group 1) and Min and Q1 of the row n+1 (group 2)

For example, I have this input

```
df1
  taille    min    q1   med   moy    q3   max
1 Petite     42  54.5    77  88.5  130    160
2 Moyenne    25  89.2   144 185.   283.   430
3 Grande     48 219.    255 249.   290    385

df2
  taille        min    q1   med   moy    q3   max
1 Petite          1     4     5  4.74     6     8
2 Moyenne         4    18    24 22.4     28    37
3 Grande         16    43    50 51.4     60    92
4 Très Grande    51    80    90 98.1    108   276
```

and I want this output with borne, the function multipetal below

```
df1
  taille    min    q1   med   moy    q3   max  borne
1 Petite     42  54.5   77    88.5  130   160   101
2 Moyenne    25  89.2   144   185.  283.  430   245
3 Grande     48  219.   255   249.  290   385   NA

df2
  taille        min    q1   med   moy    q3   max  borne
1 Petite          1     4     5  4.74     6     8  9
2 Moyenne         4    18    24 22.4     28    37  31
3 Grande         16    43    50 51.4     60    92  71
4 Très Grande    51    80    90 98.1    108   276  NA
```

Do you have an idea to deal with it?

Thanks,

Aymeric

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a description of `tt_202` and the other variables. Your example should be a minimal reproducible example. Also provide an example of what your current output is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`. `lead` gives access to the next row. Also, I use `lapply` to apply a function to every entry of a list which is often the easier way to do it in R instead of using a `for` loop:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "  taille    min    q1   med   moy    q3   max
1 Petite     42  54.5    77  88.5  130    160
2 Moyenne    25  89.2   144 185.   283.   430
3 Grande     48 219.    255 249.   290    385", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "  taille        min    q1   med   moy    q3   max
1 Petite          1     4     5  4.74     6     8
2 Moyenne         4    18    24 22.4     28    37
3 Grande         16    43    50 51.4     60    92
4 TrèsGrande    51    80    90 98.1    108   276", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test_list <- list(df1, df2)

library(dplyr)

multipetal <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(bourne = (q3 + max + lead(q1) + lead(min)) / 4)
}

test_list <- lapply(test_list, multipetal)
test_list

[[1]]
   taille min    q1 med   moy  q3 max bourne
1  Petite  42  54.5  77  88.5 130 160 101.05
2 Moyenne  25  89.2 144 185.0 283 430 245.00
3  Grande  48 219.0 255 249.0 290 385     NA

[[2]]
      taille min q1 med   moy  q3 max bourne
1     Petite   1  4   5  4.74   6   8   9.00
2    Moyenne   4 18  24 22.40  28  37  31.00
3     Grande  16 43  50 51.40  60  92  70.75
4 TrèsGrande  51 80  90 98.10 108 276     NA
```